'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral error when trying to save image to disk during a SSRS report
I am trying to use a dll to create a barcode image based on an ID number I get from the report. When reaching the point of saving the image created based on this ID number I get this error
'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
Prior to this I tried to use a barcode font which worked the way up until I needed to print the report. At that point the ID number would revert back to numbers instead of the barcode font when the print preview was visible. I gave up trying to make the font work and instead attempted to use a dll inside the report to create an image and then insert it back into the report.
I have allowed SQL Server Reporting services principle
NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices
I have allowed the dll full permission.
The problem occurs at this line.
Linearbitmap.Save(fullFilePath + LinearBarCodeFileName(rmaID_));
The barcode type is Code39.
Is it even possible to have a dll inside the report and write a PNG to a disk? If it is and I am simply missing a permission somewhere for SSRS to do so are there places that I haven't mentioned here that I should check permissions in?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
